# Is there a method for solving the inverse of a function involving the inverse of another function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a function we'll call $g(x)$ that I find is impossible to solve for $x$.  And I have a function $f(x)$ where some of it is written in terms of $g^{-1}(x)$.  Is it possible to find $f^{-1}(x)$?

Since this is probably dependent on the functions that I'm working with, below are the functions

$$g(x)=\frac{\left(n+s^x\right)\ln\left(n+s^x\right)-s^x\ln\left(s^x\right)-n}{n\ln s}$$

$$f(x)=s^{g^{-1}(x)}\left(x\ln s+1-\ln\left(s^{g^{-1}(x)}\right)\right)$$

and $s$ and $n$ are constants.

I realize that I cannot get an explicit formula for $g^{-1}(x)$, but regardless it feels like it may be possible to get $f^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$.  This is my question.  Is it possible?

***Edit***:  For my purposes, I have been able to simplify the above function $f$ to what it is now.

Comment: When you say that $g(x)$ is "impossible to solve" do you mean you cannot find $g^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: I think I have completely misunderstood your question, so I am deleting my attempted answer.

Comment: Your function $g$ looks dauntingly complicated. You should expect that an explicit formula for the inverse would be completely beyond reach. Rather, you should investigate numerical methods.